# Variable ListView Item layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a ListView item layout file with 3 TextViews in a LinearLayout.

[image: ListView Item layout]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Count"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/seen_background"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        tools:text="5,000" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            tools:text="War and Peace" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            tools:text="Some subtitle" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</LinearLayout>
```

Depending on user preferences, I either want to show the subtitle TextView or not. My question is, what is the best way to accomplish this? It seems that I have two options:
1. Create two different ListView Item layouts - one with subtitle and one without.
2. Use the same ListView Item layout and set subtitle.setVisibility(false).

What is preferred? If I used option #2, which seems preferable to me, I am not sure where/when to setVisibility on this TextView. The ListView uses a SimpleCursorAdapter.

And if I setVisibility(View.GONE) I believe that this makes the Title TextView take up the whole right side, which is what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is preferred?

Well, the best solution is to replace the obsolete `ListView` with `RecyclerView`.

Independent of that... for a minor per-row change like this, modifying the row layout (e.g., toggling view visibility) is perfectly reasonable. If there were more substantial changes, then having multiple row layouts would be preferable, but that seems like overkill for this case.

> I am not sure where/when to setVisibility on this TextView. The ListView uses a SimpleCursorAdapter.

It has been a while since I used `SimpleCursorAdapter` (did I mention that `ListView` is obsolete?). You basically have your choice of:

- Overriding `bindView()`, toggling the visibility in your overridden method, then chaining to the superclass `bindView()` implementation for all of its normal logic, or
- Using a `ViewBinder` and `setViewBinder()`

In either case, make sure that for *every* row you *always* set the visibility to what it should be (e.g., visible or gone). Rows get recycled with `ListView`, and so the initial state of this view is indeterminate.

Comment: I did setVisibility(View.GONE) in the ViewBinder (setViewValue()). This seems to work well. However, there is a noticeable gap where the now invisible TextView was. It is small but perceptible. My understanding of View.GONE is that it should not take up any space.

Comment: And yes, ListView is replaced with RecyclerView. Is there a quick cheat sheet on what it takes to convert from old to new?

Comment: @JJJones_3860: "My understanding of View.GONE is that it should not take up any space." -- it will not take up any space. However, bear in mind that there are other things in your layout that will affect the size and position of your remaining widgets.

Comment: You can see my List Item Layout file above, if I set the subtitle textview to GONE, why would there be space under the title textview in that row? If I remove the subtitle textview from the layout, there is no space. I am confounded by this one.

Comment: Found it! Thanks. Did not add marginTop and marginBottom to my embedded LinearLayout as on the Count TextView. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Set visibility to GONE and it should be as you said

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Arraylist of objects with the Listview than add an extra variable boolean to that object

```
   public Boolean isvisible;
```

set default to true
and do this in your adapter

```
if(!isvisible){
textview2.setvisibility=View.INVISIBLE;//orView.GONE
else{
textview2.setvisibiliti=View.VISIBLE;
```